# Random point in a line in n-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a line in N-dimensional space (or 3-dimensional space for simplicity) and we know its parameters. Is there any way to find the coordinates of a random point in that line systematically?

*By systematically I mean an algorithm that do the process.*

Comment: Hi, your question is not too specific. In which form is the line given? Then, in which part of the line should the random point be? If you do not specify anything, then the point is with a large probability very far away. And what probability distribution do you want?

Comment: What's wrong with using `RandomPoint` and `Line` for example a 4D line `RandomPoint[Line[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}]]` ? It works in 1D,2D,3D,4D,... etc. and it's uniform over the line.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are in an affine space; given a point `{p1,p2,p3}` on your line and a vector `{u1,u2,u3}` on the line, any point on the line has coordinates `{p1,p2,p3}+x*{u1,u2,u3}`, where $x$ is real. You still have to determine what distribution you want for $x$ (saying "a random point" is not enough). If you choose a normal distribution you could write something like

```
mu = 0; sigma = 1;
p = {p1,p2,p3} + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]] * {u1,u2,u3}
```